# In C, shall I use FLUSH every time I use scanf to get rid of buffer?

Tags: c, while-loop, buffer, scanf

As the title says, shall I use

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

every time I use scanf?
And can someone explain the logic behind

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

No, you generally don't need to do that. The loop you posted reads characters from `stdin` until it encounters one that's not `\n`. The way you wrote it, that last non-newline **character is lost** just like the newlines.

Typical problems or the need for "flushing" can be avoided by:

- Not mixing `scanf` with other input methods. For example don't mix it with `fgets`
- Preceding format specifiers with a space where space isn't ignored and you want it ignored

For example, to ignore blanks, instead of `scanf("%c"...)` use `scanf(" %c"..)`.

---

That aside, when you have complex input to read in you might want to:

- Read entire strings with `fgets`, which you can then parse as you please with `sscanf`, `strtok` et al. It may look like a contradiction, recommending `sscanf` where `scanf` is inadequate. The point is once you have the full string stored safely using `fgets`, you've got considerably more freedom to analyze it, throw portions that don't match, do a `strchr` here and there etc
- Use languages (with libraries) better suited for the job, like python or perl to reduce the task to a simpler problem
- Use a full-blown lexer

Comment: @Cubbi I only learned about it by chance. I too am surprised it isn't more frequently mentioned.

Comment: Great answer. One thing to add: `scanf` is simply not an appropriate function for reading interactive or remotely free-form input. The only place it's useful without painful hackery around it is for reading input that's known to be in a specific form, such as a text file full of whitespace-delimited numbers, common in certain types of scientific and mathematical computing. If you're accepting lines of interactive user input, you **really** need to be doing line-based reading (`fgets`) and parsing it yourself or with `sscanf`.